# Save referenced resource on update_attributes (create nested resource on edit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested

I have something like issue tracking system where there are issues and they have some comments.

Now on one page I want to give user an option to edit some stuff of "issue" as well as add a comment. Editing of and issue is a standard stuff like in */edit* but also I want to create a comment and validate if it's not blank.

I've figured out that I can build a comment and make a form for it, but how should I check simultaneously that both issue attributes and comment attributes are valid? Because each update should be followed by a new comment, but I don't want to create a new comment if the issue attributes are no valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by first adding `fails_validation?` methods to both your `Issues` and `Comments` models to check for problems.

Second, you will have to manually load the `@issue` form data from `params[]` and validate it BEFORE you save it (can't use `update_attributes(params[:issue])`.)  Create a new `Comment` and load it via `params[]`.  Then you can test the validation on both models and go back to the `edit` action if either fails.

If both pass you can save `@issue` and then `@comment` as normal.

```
def update
  @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
  # manually transfer form data to the issue model
  @issue.title = params[:issue][:title]
  @issue.body = params[:issue][:body]
  #...

  @comment = @issue.comments.new(params[:comment])

  # validate both @issue and @comment
  if @issue.fails_validation? || @comment.fails_validation?
    flash[:error] =  "Your edits or your comment did not pass validation."
    render :action => "edit", 
  end

  # validation passed, save @issue then @comment
  respond_to do |format|
    if @issue.save
      @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @issue, notice: 'Issue successfully updated. Comment created' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @issue.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: Why do you say that update_attributes will not check for validation errors? It calls save internally which runs validations.

Comment: It is a logic flow issue, not a update_attributes() functionality issue.  If you use update_attributes() it will both load up your model from params[] and save it (you are correct.)  However, in this problem you want to load up your model from params[] but NOT save it until after you have performed the validation on the data that came in via params[].  That's why I made the comment that you can't use update_attributes() - because it will save your model before you have validated the param[] updates.

Comment: @salil - I was assuming that he was not using nested attributes, hence the need for the separate validation process.  If he is using nested attributes, then your answer is obviously the preferred approach.

Comment: The question was worded "...check simultaneously that both issue attributes and comment attributes are valid..." You can't meet this requirement using traditional Rails model validation.  update_attributes will save the first model's update before the second has been validated (unless you are doing nested attributes, as you pointed out.)  This is why I pointed out that he will need to write his own validation routines that are independent of the save functionality.

Comment: You are right. For what he wants to do, it's much easier if he just uses nested_attributes and validates the whole @issue object at one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the comment model and the issue model in their respective classes. 
It is not clear to me whether you are using 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' in Issue for comments. If you are, then the standard IssueController#update will not save the record if issue is invalid and consequently, it will not create the comment records as well.

Here is the standard IssueController#update:

```
class IssueController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
    if @issue.update_attributes(params[:issue])
      redirect_to issues_path, notice: 'issue updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end
```